# creating the wcf service client causes a InvalidOperationException

Tags: wcf, wcf-endpoint, wcfserviceclient

I have 2 solutions:

In solution 1 I have a web project with wcf service references.
In solution 2 I have a wpf project where I start the following wcf client:

When I create an instance of my wcf client:

```
using (var client = new LSKTicketServiceReference.LSKTicketServiceClient())
{
   // client.do()
}
```

I get this error:

"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'LSKTicketServiceReference.ILSKTicketService'..."

But in the app.config of the facade project used by the wpf project I have this endpoint defined:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>      
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILSKTicketService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>

      <endpoint address="http://localhost:53776/LSKTicketService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILSKTicketService" contract="ILSKTicketService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILSKTicketService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

So what is the problem here? I defined my endpoint.

Comment: Did you try to add this service config in web config of wpf project?

Comment: In solution 1 web.config there is nothing wcf related because we have other services and they work. I just tried to make this one work as the others... BUT i just found out, that the wpf project app.config needs a missing endpoint... I try that later.

Comment: The missing endpoint in the wpf`s app.config did not solve the the problem, I still get that error.

Comment: You are looking in some other config may be. Add some key in your config and read it before `using (var client = new LSKTicketServiceReference.LSKTicketServiceClient())` just to be sure you are looking in right config.

Comment: ok I found the problem I put the endpoint in the other config file as I said, but the contract string was not correct... No I get a deserializer exception coz of a certain object missing a enum member attribute, but when I remove that I reach the server side hooorayyy

Comment: Congrants. Good you managed to solve this. You can add answer and mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was NOT that the creation of the LSKTicketServiceClient was created in a Facade project.

But that the Facade project was referenced by the WPF app project and here was the endpoint configuration missing in the app.config.